# missing return statement when I run my app in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to write an app where the user clicks on the marker and starts the camera activity. I've coded this but it does not work, what can I do?
When I try to run this app in Android Studio, I get 2 errors :

> Error: missing return statement

And

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. 
>   Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

I've tried to search on Google, but I couldn't find the solution.
Here is my code :

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap1, mMap2;

    //Other methods removed

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker){
        if (marker.equals(mMap1)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, CameraView.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already see the marker on the map then your `onMarkerClick()` should get their arguments :

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

    if (marker.equals(marker))
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, CameraView.class) ;

        startActivity(intent);

    }
    return false;

}
```

return statement is false indeed.

Comment: Thank you. It works I guess, because the app stops when I press on the marker. What can I do ?